# Restrict youtube embedding on other site

Tags: video, youtube, embed

I have some youtube videos on my site and I want only the members can  embed all the videos on to their site also., Non members are only allowed to view not to embed, is there a way to do it??

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

For the average video poster, you can only disable and enable embedding globally, not on a domain-by-domain basis.

However, according to this webpage by Google, restricting embedding is possible on a domain by domain basis if you are part of cms.youtube.com. To restrict embedding, the article states blocking all embedding, then creating a whitelist of allowed domains.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6301625?hl=en

I believe in order to use this you must be accepted to use the Youtube CMS and Content ID. To sign up: https://www.youtube.com/content_id_signup

More information on Youtube CMS and Content ID is available here:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2797370?hl=en

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot enable and disable embedding of YouTube videos on a site-by-site basis. Either your videos can be embedded on any site, or they can only be viewed on youtube.com.

Details, under "Disable embedding": http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171780

Comment: This is no longer the case. I'm unsure of the details, but it's now possible to restrict what domains your Youtube videos can be embedded on. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407482/youtube-embed-gives-restricted-from-playback-on-certain-sites-error-despite-ap).

Comment: There's nothing on the YouTube site which appears to expose that functionality to video uploaders. I suspect it's only available to certain large content owners which Google has special deals with (e.g, TV/movie studios, music labels, etc).